# How to put random objects onto a stack without having the objects turn into DeferredElementImpl?

Tags: java, class, nodelist

I'm trying to put both `Strings` and `Nodes` onto a `Stack`. I use the NodeList method `item(int)` to obtain a `Node` from the `NodeList`. Then, I push this `Node` to the `Stack`. My only problem is that I doesn't see it as a `Node` unless I have something wrong.

When I call `getClass()` method on the `Node` and it returns this:

```
class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementImpl
```

When I call that same method on `NodeList` (`getClass()`), it returns this:

```
class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl
```

Both times when I call the `getClass()` method, it is before I put it on the `Stack`. I want to be able to any different `Objects` onto a `Stack`, and be able to filter through all the objects on the Stack to figure out which class they belong to. Thanks!

Comment: show us the declaration of the Stack, and where you push Items on the Stack and where you pop them out.

Comment: Before I even put them on the Stack, it says it's the same class.

Comment: we can help you when you show us the relevant code.

Comment: No. I'm expecting that the Node come from the Node class and NodeList come from NodeList class. I want to be able to grab the Node (From anywhere, not just the Stack), and from that Node get the class it belongs to (Since I am putting it on a Stack with other Objects, I will need to make it an Object temporarily). Since I'm putting it on a Stack and making it an object, I don't know the pattern of the stack whether I would be getting a String or Node when I pop from the Stack, so I need to be able to determine the object I pop which class it's from.

Comment: That's why I used the method getClass() above, because I would use that method find out (when I pop the Object from the Stack) what to do with it. Hard to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node and NodeList are interfaces not class.

`instanceof` was made for you.

This code :

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf   = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder        db    = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document               doc   = db.parse( new File( "build.xml" ));
NodeList               nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName( "target" );
System.err.println( nodes instanceof NodeList );
System.err.println( nodes.item( 0 ) instanceof Node );
System.err.println( nodes.item( 0 ) instanceof Element );
```

outputs:

```
true
true
true
```

You may write, after `stack.pop()`, `if( var instance of String )` or `if( var instanceof Node )`... but IMHO it's not a good idea to mix different type into a single container.

Comment: Thank you!! It worked!! I knew there was probably something about the Node and NodeList classes I didn't know about. I'm new to those classes.